# Cant prove this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

- Let $\,\mathrm{f}:\mathbb{N}^{2} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $\,\mathrm{f}\left(n,k\right) =
  \frac{1}{2}\,\left(n + k\right)\left(n + k + 1\right) + k$.
- Let $n, k, n', k'$ be natural integers where $n + k > n' + k'$.
- I want to prove that we have
  $\,\mathrm{f}\left(n,k\right) \geq \,\mathrm{f}\left(n',k'\right) + n' + k + 1$.
- The exercice gives the tip that: $n + k > n' + k'$ also means that
  $n + k \geq n' + k' + 1$.

I have tried to manipulate the expression but it doesn't help much and I am stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}f(n,k)&=\frac12(n+k)(n+k+1)+k\tag1\\
&\geq \frac12(n'+k'+1)(n'+k'+1+1)+k\tag2\\
&=\frac12(n'+k')(n'+k'+1)+\frac12(n'+k'+1+n'+k')+\frac12+k\tag3\\
&=f(n',k')+n'+k+1\tag4
\end{align}$$

Explanation of steps: 
$(1)\to(2)$: Use the tip which says $n+k\geq n'+k'+1$. (we use it on both brackets) 
$(2)\to(3)$: Expand using $$(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$$where in this case, $$a=n'+k',b=1,c=n'+k'+1,d=1$$
$(3)\to(4)$: simplify and use definition of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, about k' I don't understand where you think there might be a mistake?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise You wrote that you wish to prove $$f(n,k)\geq f(n',k')+n'+\color{red}k+1$$ whereas I proved $$f(n,k)\geq f(n',k')+n'+\color{red}{k'}+1$$

Comment: I checked again and my version is correct, it really is + n' + k + 1

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Ah I see what I was doing wrong - I assumed $f(n',k')=\frac12(n'+k')(n'+k'+1)+\color{red}k$, when it should have been $f(n',k')=\frac12(n'+k')(n'+k'+1)+\color{red}{k'}$. This fixes the problem :)

Comment: Oh thank you !  Unfortunately I don't understand how you get from the first two to the last two lines ? (where is the inequality gone)

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Added this in too :)